# PC makes noise while on and off

Tags: hp-pavilion, noise

my PC sometimes makes crackling noises while it's on and I was wondering if there was something wrong. It sounds like something is inside my PC, but I don't know for sure. I have a HP Pavilion that I just brought a month ago. Whenever I turn on or off my computer, it makes this buzzing sound that lasts a short time. When my PC is off, it makes a little noise and you can't hear it unless you get close. Is a normal Pc supposed to be absolutely silent? Also, I forgot to mention that it sometimes makes noises that sound like a car engine. The noise is not very loud.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be hearing any buzzing. Normally the only thing you should be hearing from the PC are the fans (may sound like humming) or if you have a cd in the cd tray and load that you can hear it spinning.

I would check to see if there is anything loose inside.

How old is the computer? Are you using a mechanical hard drive or a SSD?

Comment: I brought it about a month ago. I don't know why my Pc is like this. I think it uses a mechanical hard drive.

Comment: My best guess it is a failing hard drive. There are not too many moving parts in the computer. Besides that maybe a more serious issue with the power supply "crackling"? If so it could be a fire hazard. @Jeanne

Comment: I'll probably return this Pc and get a new one. If it could be a fire hazard, then I have to get rid of this Pc immediately. Thank you. @DidYouPingMe